# How to install Sql 2012 on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having trouble installing sql server 2012 on windows 8.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've never done it myself, but it looks like you may be having a .Net version problem.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2681562

Take a look at the section titled:

**Known SQL Server 2012 setup and migration issues** 
- By default, Windows 8 includes the .NET Framework 4.0. However, the following SQL Server 
2012 components depend on the .NET Framework 3.5:

- SQL Server 2012 Database Engine
- Replication Service
- SQL Server Data Tools
- Data Quality Service
- Master Data Service
- Reporting Service Native Mode
- Full-Text Search

Therefore, we recommend that you enable the .NET Framework 3.5 before you install SQL Server 2012 in a stand-alone or clustered environment to help prevent any possible SQL Server setup failures.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx) as a guideline.

- Check and make sure .Net framework 3.5 SP1 is installed.
- check and make sure .Net framework 4.0 is installed
- check and make sure Windows PowerShell 2.0 is installed

Comment: I have all those installed(expect 4.0...I have 4.5)